# How to align inner divs in centre or bottom based on %

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my JS application, I have a panel that is spited in 3 sections each with `width: 100%` and `height:33.33%` then in each section I want to have some divs.

- In the middle section, the inner divs must stay in middle vertically
  and horizontally.
- In the bottom section, the inner divs must stay in
  the bottom but middle horizontally.

```js
$(".panel2").hide();
$(".panel1").click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(".panel2").show();
});
$(".panel2").click(function() {
  $(".panel1").show();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
div.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

div.box > .blur {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://goo.gl/0VTd9W);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
}

div.box > .panel1,
div.box > .panel2 {
  width: 100%;
  Height: 100%;
  Background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

div.box > .panel2 {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/** sub sections **/

div.panel1 > .top,
div.panel1 > .middle,
div.panel1 > .bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.33%;
  border: 1px dashed #000;
}

div.middle > div,
div.bottom > div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px dashed #000;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="blur"></div>
  <div class="panel1">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel2">Panel 2</div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have implemented the divs but cannot align them in the described positions since the parent divs are percentage based.

Any idea to align them?

Comment: Is targeting old browsers like IE9 a requirement?

Comment: @azium well its not a requirement but i prefer to have at least a similar look in IE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways that you can achieve your desire situation such as  `transform: translate(-50%);`, `position:absolute` and negative `margin`, `display:inline-block;`, `display: flex;` and etc. Here, `display:inline-block;` is used. You can add one more div(`.centered-vertically`), give `height:100%;` and don't forget [remove extra spaces](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) which is occurred by `display:inline-block;` and finally, use `vertical-align` property to align them to `bottom`, `middle` and `top`. However, here is completed code.

```js
$(".panel2").hide();
$(".panel1").click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(".panel2").show();
});
$(".panel2").click(function() {
  $(".panel1").show();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
div.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

div.box > .blur {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://goo.gl/0VTd9W);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
}

div.box > .panel1,
div.box > .panel2 {
  width: 100%;
  Height: 100%;
  Background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

div.box > .panel2 {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/** sub sections **/

div.panel1 > .top,
div.panel1 > .middle,
div.panel1 > .bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.33%;
  border: 1px dashed #000;
}

div.middle > div:not(.centered-vertically),
div.bottom > div:not(.centered-vertically) {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px dashed #000;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin: 10px;
}

div.bottom > div:not(.centered-vertically)
{
  vertical-align:bottom;
  }

div.middle > .centered-vertically,
div.bottom > .centered-vertically
{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  height:100%;
  
  }

div.middle
{
  text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="blur"></div>
  <div class="panel1">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="centered-vertically"></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="centered-vertically"></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel2">Panel 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is the simplest solution. Simply add the following rules to your middle and bottom containers:

```
.middle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bottom {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/EPKdow?editors=110)